# Кластер и сортировка его объектов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет . 
Не могу решить проблему :  загружаю объекты  в json формате (  все  отсортировано  так как надо ) в  ObjectManager с опцией clusterize: true.  Все бы отлично . НО !  Никак не могу отсортировать объекты в кластере ( балуне )  . Объекты -  события по адресу в определенную дату. Естественно, необходимо отсортировать по датам . Никак ...  Помогите , плиз !!!

```
        ymaps.ready( init );

                function init() {

                    ymaps.geolocation.get().then( function ( res ) {
                        var mapContainer = $( '#mapgrumers' ),
                            bounds = res.geoObjects.get( 0 ).properties.get( 'boundedBy' ),
                            // Рассчитываем видимую область для текущей положения пользователя.
                            mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
                                bounds, [ mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height() ]
                            );

                        myMap = new ymaps.Map( 'mapgrumers', mapState, {
                            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                        } );
                        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager( {
                            clusterize: true,
                            gridSize: 50,
                            geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
                            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
                        } );




        objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
        objectManager.clusters.options.set('balloonContentLayout', 'cluster#balloonAccordion');             

                        data = {
                            rang: 'КЧФ'
                        };
                        data[ 'm' ] = 0;
                        $.ajax( {
                            url: "getpointsshow.php",
                            data: data,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function ( html ) {
                                objectManager.add( html );

                            myMap.geoObjects.add( objectManager ); 
                            }
                        } )


                    }, function ( e ) {
                        // Если местоположение невозможно получить, то просто создаем карту.
                        createMap( {
                            center: [ 55.751574, 37.573856 ],
                            zoom: 2
                        } );
                    } );

                }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

OM отображает объекты в балуне в порядке их добавления, если объекты при добавлении отсортированы как надо, то и в балуне они будут отображаться в правильном порядке. Если это не так у вас работает, то нужен пример страницы или пример jsfiddle где можно увидеть проблему.

Comment: При формировании json -   объекты добавляются отсортированными ..    по sql запросу .  $sql= "select * from  `show-katalog`  where data>=now()  order by data ,adress " ;
  Картинку  выложила в первый пост.     А  страница - по адресу  https://melodiyavesny.ru/show-map.php

Comment: В хинте пробовала дату первой поставить ...  все никак . Да и по идее , нет смысла ... как я понимаю .